# How to correct "Failed to start macro 'VerifyUsers'" after site collection restore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-services

We are getting the error "Failed to start macro 'VerifyUsers'" after site collection restore of a site collection containing Access Web DB site. This is SP2010 Enterprise SP1 + FebCU.  Here are repro steps:

- Create a site collection using the blank site template
- add a subsite using one of the OOB web databases (ie Asset Web Database site template)
- Browse to access db site
- Observe it works as expected
- Backup the site collection using Backup-spsite
- Remove the site collection using Remove-spsite
- Restore the site collection using Restore-spsite
- Browse to access db site
- Observe error 'Failed to start macro 'VerifiyUsers'

ULS logs report:

Exception Very serious error happened when trying to open web to start data macro workflow. Macro has not been started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id d52542f0-f36a-4ff4-af2b-35214e920b19 could not be found.

Get-spsite confirms there is no site with the given id. Presumably, some part of the access db is referencing the old site id, though I cannot find it in web or site properties, or by opening the db in access and examining the macro, etc.